# How to get string reference of image from a database and convert to the real image

Tags: android, database

I'm developing an app which downloads a json objects into database,this is done so that the users can interact with the data without the knowladge of the data source.
I have managed to download the required fields from the json API into my database as string and I can display all fileds using textfields however I have 100 images which I want to present as images and not as string.
I have tried to implement several methods so that I can display the images.And followed several tutorails to see if I could find a solution to my problem.
[1](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/store-imagesfiles-database),[2](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) and more.

Below is my DBHelper.

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String sql = String.format( "create table %s ( %s int primary key, %s 
            TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %S TEXT, %S TEXT, %S TEXT)",
            TABLE,C_ID 
             ,C_IDENTIFIER,C_PRICE,C_BEDROOMS,C_ADDRESS,C_PROPERTYTYPE,C_PHOTOS);

    Log.d(TAG, "OnCreate sql :"+sql);

    db.execSQL(sql);
    }

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("drop table if exists "+TABLE);
    Log.d(TAG, "onUpdate dropped table" + TABLE);
    this.onCreate(db);
}
```

Here is the class which gets the fields from the database,which works fine other than the image.

```
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
private CursorAdapter dataSource;
private static final String fields[] = { "identifier", "price", "bedrooms",
        "ADDRESS", "PROPERTYTYPE", "PHOTOTHUMBNAILURL", BaseColumns._ID };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.database);
    DBHelper helper = new DBHelper(this);
    database = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor data = database.query(DBHelper.TABLE, fields, null, null, null,
            null, null);

    dataSource = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this,
            R.layout.list,
            data,
            fields,
            new int[] { R.id.identifier2, R.id.price2, R.id.bedrooms2,
                    R.id.address2, R.id.propertytype2, R.id.propertyPhoto2 });

    setListAdapter(dataSource);


    // selecting single ListView item
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {


            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String identifier = ((TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.identifier2)).getText().toString();

            String price = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.price2))
                    .getText().toString();
            String bedrooms = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.bedrooms2))
                    .getText().toString();
            String address = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.address2))
                    .getText().toString();
            String propertyType = ((TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.propertytype2)).getText().toString();

  String photoThumbnailUrl = ((TextView)  
   view.findViewById(R.id.propertyPhoto2)).getText()
                    .toString();





        }
    });
    database.close();
    helper.close();

}
```

When I try this( String photoThumbnailUrl = ((TextView)
       view.findViewById(R.id.propertyPhoto2)).getText()
                        .toString();)It works and displays the images as string however when I try to use this 
     (ImageView image =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1);
        ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByteArray);
        Bitmap Image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);) it does not work.

Any solution or advice, thanks in advance.

Comment: You've shown us just about everything about the program except the relevant part :). Where are you acquiring the `imageByteArray`?

Comment: Are you making a web request to actually grab the images?

Comment: @Christopher Perry,yes that is correct.I'm making a web request and I,m able to recieve the fields required.my main problem is to display the images in the database.These are stored a field "PHOTOTHUMBNAILURL" like this:http://media.xxx.co.uk/3k/2265/35402969/2265_9897_IMG_00_0000_max_200x138.jpg.

Comment: @Brain,my problem seems simple but i can't find the solution all though I have tried number of methods.All I need is to display these images from the database as images but not string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so you have the URLs to your photos... so what's the problem? Make web requests for the photos using the URLs your first request returned to you.

I'd use this, it's pretty awesome:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html

Comment: @ Christopher Perry,thanks again for your reply.Preferably I would love to display the images and the text from the database nevertheless if until then I cannot do that I will have to use this approach.
I have already done the hard work and managed to retrieve the json objects and store them in my database.I can display these fields from the database using text field however the image is displayed as text and there is my only problem.

Comment: I don't think you are understanding the problem. Your JSON objects contain the URLs for your images. You need to make web requests using those URLs to actually get the images. Text != Bitmap.

Comment: ,if you don't mind can you please explain the problem further.I realy need help.

Comment: Ok, so usually when you grab a chunk of data that has images, the actual bitmaps don't come in that chunk, they come in the form of a URL string which points to the Bitmap on the web. You have to download the images separately using the URLs. The code from the link I showed you can do this for you, you'd just do Bitmap theImage = ImageDownloader.downloadBitmap(URL GOES HERE); Then you put the bitmap into the ImageView. Make sure you download the images on a background thread or you'll hang the UI thread.